# Opening modal popup for edit record in MVC Grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a scenario that i have a grid in which i am displaying employee's records. In each row there is a edit link. On that link i want to open a partial view in modal popup with that record but i don't want to use $.ajax for filling partial view in modal popup div.
Is there any way to achieve it?

```
<table width="600px">
<tr>
    <th align="center">
        Ename
    </th>
    <th align="center">
        Sal
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td align="center">
        Manish
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        20000
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="/Home/Edit/100">Edit</a> |
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        Ravi
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        10000
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="/Home/Edit/101">Edit</a> |
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        Dinesh
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        15000
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="/Home/Edit/102">Edit</a> |
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        Vikash
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        12000
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="/Home/Edit/103">Edit</a> |
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are your records in a table?

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the table structure? Include the thead and tbody

Comment: I have posted code above.Please review

Comment: Sorry, could you post the pure html output for the table? I need to see what class the anchor tags <a> have

Comment: I have updated code in description.Please have a review

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a bootstrap modal to show the table.

HTML ...

`<div id="alertModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Edit a Record</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table>    <!-- This is where we will show the selected record -->
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th align="center">Ename</th>
                            <th align="center">Sal</th>
                            <th><!-- Put a save button here, maybe?--></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                    Close</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->`

1. Copy the contents of the table row and display it in the bootstrap table

Javascript ...

```
. . .

/* Assuming your table has an id of 'myTable' the following code,
will trigger a click event handler when one of you MVC links are clicked */
$('#myTable').find('a[href*="/Home/Edit/"]').each(function(){

    $(this).click(function(){

        //Clone the table row which has a link that was clicked
        var $tr = $(this).parents('tr').clone();

        //Empty the contents of the table
        $('#editModal').find('table tbody').empty();

        //Add the cloned row into the table
        $('#editModal').find('table tbody').append($tr);

        //Show the modal
        $('#editModal').modal('show')

        ... //Code to update the table below the modal, up to you..

    });
});
```

Comment: It makes sense. But is it possible to pick fresh data from database using mvc async call like ajax form. I am asking this if suppose my page is opened from a more than a hour and some other user change data in that case i will not be able to pick fresh data. So can we return partial view using mvc way.

Comment: I'm not sure...I'm not that familiar with asp mvc... What I can say though, is that you can force the user to refresh the page using jquery. Just capture a timestamp on page load, then check if more than five minutes has passed. If true, reload the page else, show the modal/